# Cost of living in China as an international student

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, international-students, china

I've just been offered PhD admission in SUStech located in Shenzhen, China. The tuition fee is 10,000rmb per year and the accommodation is 1,300rmb per year.

As an international student, is 80,000-100,000rmb per annum as a stipend be enough to cover all my expenses considering the location and have savings?

Comment: Would you clarify _the accommodation is 1,300rmb per year_? Do you mean housing expense? How many people share a room? 1,300rmb per year seems very low to me.

Comment: @scaahu, the expenses am referring too is the general expenses. The accommodation in the school hostel is 1,300rmb per year in a single room dormitory for postgraduate

Comment: Thank you very much @scaaahu

Comment: To anyone who wonders why I had to ask the OP to clarify. According to current exchange rate (1 **:** 0.14), 1,300rmb is about US$182.00. This means you pay US$182 for a single room for one year.

Comment: @scaahu Charging just 100 rmb per month for a room per student seems normal around Guangdong. However it probably means it’s not a great place to live. Getting about 80k rmb per year is okay but not great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am from Shenzhen. If your numbers are accurate, then that's a very, very good stipend.

You have about 70-90k RMB excluding accommodation and tuition each year. The university cafeteria is probably about 20 RMB or less per meal. If you want to eat out frequently for better food, then maybe closer to 30-50 RMB per meal (if you include the occasional 150 RMB Cantonese restaurant, the average might be closer to 40-50 RMB). Utilities, etc., shouldn't exceed 1000 RMB per month.

Assuming you don't have many expensive habits (e.g. spending a lot of your salary in Macao), that leaves you about 30-50k in savings per year, which is pretty decent even for (working) young people in Shenzhen.